# SQL Return a column if it exists or return the value that's used for querying

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query to return a list of values from table T1. If the record exists in the table I return the column value. Else I return the respective param value that I query the table with.
Ex: Table_1 exists. I need to query column Table_1.column_1 from the respective table.
Select Table_1.column_1 from Table_1 where Table_1.column_2= x(param value1,value2,value3) IF EXISTS ELSE RETURN value.

If the records exists the final o/p will be x1,x2,x3.
Suppose there isn't a match for value3, I expect the o/p to be x1,x2,value3.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks

So far I've managed to use case statement but failed since I'm unable to return the appropriate query value.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired output, along with DDL + DML commands

Comment: This question is not clear at all but maybe you are just looking for the COALESCE function?

Comment: I tried with COALESCE function. COALESCE works if the records exists but not the value right? COALESCE(null,value) returns (value,value). In my case no record should exist for the query where column=value

Comment: Sample data-->
Column_1 | Column_2, 1 | x1, 2 | x2, 3 | x3
Query-->
`Select column_1, column_2 from table where column_2 in ('x1,x2,x5,x6')`

Desired o/p--- >  
Column_1 | Column_2, 1 | x1, 2 | x2, x5 | x5, x6 | x6

What happens here is records exists in column_2 for values x1, x2 hence 1,2 is returned in the column_1
whereas no record exists for value x5,x6 hence x5,x6 are retuned.
Is there any possible way to attain this